# Store a 2D array in redis

Tags: database, redis

I have a 2D array to store in redis and I see two solutions: storing it as a JSON string or storing one hash per line. Which way is better?

Comment: Can you pipeline your redis reads / writes?  This seems like an appropriate case for benchmarking.

Comment: Yes I can pipeline the reads / write

Comment: "Better" depends on your isage patterns. Will it make sense to read or update a row or column at a time? Will you always be saving/reading the entire table at once? Are you optimizing for transfer speed? Serialization speed? Storage size?

Comment: It seems that the hash method is better because when you have to update the array you have to parse the JSON string and it costs a lot of time

Comment: The array will be read entirely but the values will be updated one by one.

Comment: Bear in mind that all redis collection-style objects have linear access time as a function of their size. For small lists it's easier to just use a list and store a row per value, but for larger objects, the access time will dominate and you _may_ be better off storing the whole thing in a json/pickle string. It's the sort of thing you'd have to benchmark for your application...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was faced with the same question when designing an application.  I opted on the side of simplicity.  I'm going to assume your 2d array of data represents a database row.  I would JSON encode it and store it using `SET`.  This allows me to use `MGET` and `MSET` when I want to handle multiple objects using one redis command.  If this data gets updated in my database, I `DEL` the key.  To me this is easier than trying to update a redis hash.

Hashes in redis has its advantages.  They will usually take up less memory because of "ziplist" encoding redis uses.  You can avoid serialization as well, which could be pretty significant for some apps.

Here's a sample use case for a hash for me.  Let's say I want a look up a username given a user id.  I would do `HGET user.usernames 1234`.  This would give me the username for user id 1234.  If there is a miss, I will query the DB and set it and since that data never changes, I never expire the hash.  It allows a quick look up for a common piece of data rather than pulling the entire user, unserialize, and return needed field.

For a prospective massive lookup table, I use the algorithm as purposed here: http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization
It uses multiple hashes as if there were one and utilizes ziplist encoding to save memory.

Whichever method you choose, just stay consistent.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the redis doc, it made me realize that I could use `SETRANGE` and `GETRANGE` commands to do what I need. The 2D array I need to store only contains numbers between 0 and 9 so I can store a unique string, concatenating the lines of my array. It's really fast this way.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [Redis lists?](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro) There isn't support for lists of lists, but you could either store one row per list entry, or build a list of keys referencing other lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can store each element in its own key. Just name keys so that the names contain the element's indices, and maybe the dimensions of the array as well.